# Problema de pilas en Python

Tags: python, pilas

Hace bastante tiempo que no programo en Python y la verdad es que se me está haciendo dificil. Agradezco de antemano el esfuerzo.

Tengo que crear una pila con los libros, ordenados según el orden en que nos proponemos leerlos. En una primera fase se han separado los libros en pilas por 4 temáticas: sci_fi, fantasy, crime_fiction y comics.

Debo crear una única pila con el orden que utilizaremos para leer los libros siguiendo los siguientes criterios:

1. No queremos leer dos libros de la misma temática seguidos (si se puede evitar)
2. Se quiere ir leyendo los libros en el siguiente orden de temáticas: sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy y comics.
3. Si nos encontramos con un cómic leeremos dos de seguidos.
4. Se desea mantener el orden relativo de los libros de cada una de las 4 pilas temáticas. Es decir, si un libro está sobre otro en la pila de ciencia ficción, tendra que seguir estándolo en la pila final.

Las pilas son las siguientes:

```
#Las siguientes variables muestran el contenido de las 4 pilas temáticas de libros

sci_fi = ["Dune", "Fahrenheit 451", "Ender's Game", "Hyperion", "The Foundation Vol.3", "The Foundation Vol.2", "The Foundation Vol.1", "1984"]

crime_fiction = ["Murder of the Orient Express", "The Cartel", "The Girl with the Dragon tattoo", "The Cuckoo's Calling", "The Godfather"]

fantasy = ["The Wise Man's Fear", "A Clash of Kings", "Malazan Book of the Fallen", "The Name of the Wind", "Lord of the Rings", "A Game of Thrones"]

comics = ["The Avengers vol. 3", "Spiderman vol.16", "Ghost Rider vol.2", "Spiderman vol. 15", "John Constantine vol. 5", "Batman vol. 13", "Green Arrow vol. 1"]
```

Por el momento, he intentado lo siguiente pero no sé como automatizarlo:

```
pila = []

first = sci_fi.pop()
second = crime_fiction.pop()
third = fantasy.pop()
fourth = comics.pop()
fifth = comics.pop()
sixth = sci_fi.pop()
seventh = crime_fiction.pop()
eigth = fantasy.pop()
nineth = comics.pop()
tenth = comics.pop()
eleventh = sci_fi.pop()
twelfth = crime_fiction.pop()

pila.append(first)
pila.append(second)
pila.append(third)
pila.append(fourth)
pila.append(fifth)
pila.append(sixth)
pila.append(seventh)
pila.append(eigth)
pila.append(nineth)
pila.append(tenth)
pila.append(eleventh)
pila.append(twelfth)

print(pila)
```

Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo leer nuevamente las secciones [ask] y [tour]. Lectura recomendada: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato perdón se me olvidó añadir el código. He editado el post correspondientemente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución usando comprensión de listas:

```
comics2 = comics[1:] + [comics[0]]    
pila = [titulo for linea in zip(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics, comics2) for titulo in linea ]
```

La función básica `zip` toma una serie de iterables y retorna tuplas, donde el primer elemento viene del primer iterable; el segundo elemento del segundo iterable, etc.

De esa manera si iteramos

```
for linea in zip(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics):
    print(linea)
```

obtendremos tuplas como esta:

```
('Dune', 'Murder of the Orient Express', "The Wise Man's Fear", 'The Avengers vol. 3')
('Fahrenheit 451', 'The Cartel', 'A Clash of Kings', 'Spiderman vol.16')
("Ender's Game", 'The Girl with the Dragon tattoo', 'Malazan Book of the Fallen', 'Ghost Rider vol.2')
```

Y ahí tengo un libro de cada pila. Lo único que me falta es que dos comics debe ir juntos. Para eso genero una segunda lista de comics, que es igual a la primera pero rotada en una posición:

```
comics2 = comics[1:] + [comics[0]]
```

Si agrego esta lista al `zip()` tendre dos comics en cada tupla.

Para formar la pila final voy agregando los títulos de cada tupla conservando el orden:

```
pila = []
for linea in zip(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics, comics2)
    for titulo in linea:
        pila.append(titulo)
```

Ahora, todo eso se puede expresar en forma compacta con comprensión de listas:

```
comics2 = comics[1:] + [comics[0]]
pila = [titulo for linea in zip(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics, comics2) for titulo in linea ]
```

**Demo**

```
sci_fi = ["Dune", "Fahrenheit 451", "Ender's Game", "Hyperion", "The Foundation Vol.3", "The Foundation Vol.2",
          "The Foundation Vol.1", "1984"]
crime_fiction = ["Murder of the Orient Express", "The Cartel", "The Girl with the Dragon tattoo",
                 "The Cuckoo's Calling", "The Godfather"]
fantasy = ["The Wise Man's Fear", "A Clash of Kings", "Malazan Book of the Fallen", "The Name of the Wind",
           "Lord of the Rings", "A Game of Thrones"]
comics = ["The Avengers vol. 3", "Spiderman vol.16", "Ghost Rider vol.2", "Spiderman vol. 15",
          "John Constantine vol. 5", "Batman vol. 13", "Green Arrow vol. 1"]
comics2 = comics[1:] + [comics[0]]
pila = [titulo for linea in zip(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics, comics2) for titulo in linea ]
print(pila)
```

produce

```
['Dune', 'Murder of the Orient Express', "The Wise Man's Fear", 'The Avengers vol. 3', 'Spiderman vol.16', 'Fahrenheit 451', 'The Cartel', 'A Clash of Kings', 'Spiderman vol.16', 'Ghost Rider vol.2', "Ender's Game", 'The Girl with the Dragon tattoo', 'Malazan Book of the Fallen', 'Ghost Rider vol.2', 'Spiderman vol. 15', 'Hyperion', "The Cuckoo's Calling", 'The Name of the Wind', 'Spiderman vol. 15', 'John Constantine vol. 5', 'The Foundation Vol.3', 'The Godfather', 'Lord of the Rings', 'John Constantine vol. 5', 'Batman vol. 13']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Edición: Listas de distinto largo

Lo anterior funciona si todas las listas son del mismo largo. ¿Qué pasa cuando son de largo distinto? La función `zip()` se detiene tan pronto encuentra una lista vacía, por lo que van a quedar elementos sin procesar. En este caso, libros sin poner en la pila.

Una solución es usar `zip_longest()` del paquete `itertools`, que sigue produciendo tuplas hasta acabar todos los iterables. Cuando un iterable se acaba, `zip_longest()` coloca un valor prefijado (default es `None`).

También tenemos que cambiar al forma de generar las dos listas de comics, para evitar repeticiones extras. El código queda en

```
import itertools
comics1 = comics[0::2]
comics2 = comics[1::2]
pila = [titulo for linea in itertools.zip_longest(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics1, comics2) for titulo in linea if titulo]
```

O su equivalente más explicito:

```
import itertools
comics1 = comics[0::2]
comics2 = comics[1::2]
pila = []
for linea in itertools.zip_longest(sci_fi, crime_fiction, fantasy, comics1, comics2):
    for titulo in linea:
        if titulo:
            pila.append(titulo)
```

lo cual produce:

```
['Dune', 'Murder of the Orient Express', "The Wise Man's Fear",
'The Avengers vol. 3', 'Spiderman vol.16', 'Fahrenheit 451', 
'The Cartel', 'A Clash of Kings', 'Ghost Rider vol.2', 
'Spiderman vol. 15', "Ender's Game", 
'The Girl with the Dragon tattoo', 'Malazan Book of the Fallen', 'John Constantine vol. 5', 'Batman vol. 13', 'Hyperion', 
"The Cuckoo's Calling", 'The Name of the Wind', 'Green Arrow vol. 1', 'The Foundation Vol.3', 'The Godfather', 'Lord of the Rings', 
'The Foundation Vol.2', 'A Game of Thrones', 'The Foundation Vol.1', '1984']
    

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Creo que no está bien. Revisando el resultado se repite dos veces el libro Spiderman vol.16. y tambien Spiderman vol.15. Adicionalmente, el libro "Green Arrow vol. 1" no aparece en el listado @Candid Moe

Comment: El libro 1984 tampoco aparece @Candid Moe. La respuesta es incorrecta.

Comment: @Panri93. Gracias por la observación. No había considerado que las listas fueran desiguales. Edite la respuesta.

Comment: ahora si! Gracias ;)